# Is it possible to identify a hashed bundle.js file without using HTMLWebPlugins?

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, caching, webpack-4

At the moment I am using `HTMLWebPLugins` to hash and update the `index.html` with the hashed file name. My question is, can this be done without the plugin? The reason I ask it that I would ideally not want to add an extra plugin to my project.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.